# Getting started with Celery in Django

Tags: django, django-celery

I'm currently working on a project and I'd like to integrate asynchronous task processing as well as some sort of message queue early on so that I'll be able to scale up quickly by simply adding message queue processor servers to the cluster.

I came across [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) a while back and it caught my eye. Since it's pretty well integrated with Django, I figured I'd get pretty good support with it. I'm just not really sure how to start, as there's a lot of configuration involved.

For now, I'm running just about everything out of my Django project (serving static files, pipeline, etc.) so I'd like to have a messaging queue built in to run with `django runserver` if possible. (Don't worry, this is only for development.) How can I get started using Celery with my existing Django project?

Comment: https://github.com/ask/django-celery might help. Also http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery has quite a nice documentation, also for [those getting started](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html), but two facts worth being mentioned for beginners:

- Use [djkombu](https://github.com/ask/django-kombu) as the `BROKER_BACKEND`. This will give you a pretty simple message queue for development, where all messages are stored in the SQL database used by django. Due to celery's  api you can easily replace it with a "real" message queue for production:

  `BROKER_TRANSPORT = "kombu.transport.django"`
- Django-celery has a setting [`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`](http://ask.github.com/celery/configuration.html#celery-always-eager). If set to `True` there will be no asynchronous background processing, all tasks that are getting called via celery will be run synchronously (so no need to start any additional celery workers - very useful for debugging as well).

Comment: Unfortunately, things have changed a lot in the Celery library. Can you edit your answer to work with the new APIs? Other than installing the right apps, what do I need to do to run a messaging queue directly in my Django app? It can block for now, that's fine, the main thing is being able to migrate my application to use it, so that I'm "future-proofed" so to speak.

Comment: ie: djkombu is deprecated, BROKER_BACKEND has become BROKER_TRANSPORT, etc.

Answer (score 3):

djkombu is now deprecated, the django transport is now directly integrated in the [kombu](https://github.com/ask/kombu) package.

For defining the backend in your Django `settings.py`, you can use:

```
BROKER_BACKEND = "django"
```

You can find different transport aliases from Kombu [here](https://github.com/ask/kombu/blob/master/kombu/transport/__init__.py).

This was tested with `django-celery` 2.5.5, `celery` 2.5.3 and `kombu` 2.1.8.